# PHP define function that takes key-value pair as parameter

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function that take same parameter as the [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) function. The example code is

```
<?php
function a ($k=>$v){
   echo "key is $k and value is $v";
}

a ('hello' => 'world');
```

When I try to to run this code. I got an error as the following

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (

I have put the code at http://codepad.viper-7.com/SzVBmb

I am wondering if it's possible to do what I want with php.

Edit:
  a possible way of achieving it but I don't really like:

```
 function a ($arr){
     $v = reset($arr);
     $k = key($arr);
     echo $key is $k and value is $v";
  }
  a(["hello"=>"world"]);
```

I have also searched for tuple for this kind of thing, but got no luck.

Comment: `array()` is not a function, but a language construct, function parameters are comma-separated. Just use comma and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess I can't use tuple either, right?

Answer (score 0):

you are not sending the array correctly to the function you need to add `'hello' => 'world'` inside `array()`

this is the correct one

```
function a ($array)
  {

   $key  = array_keys($array);
       echo "key is $key[0] and value is ".$array[$key[0]];
  }

 a (array('hello' => 'world'));
```

Or

```
function a ($key,$value)
  {
     echo "key is $key and value is ".$value;
  }

 a ('hello' , 'world');
```

OR

```
function a ($param)
  {
     $param = explode('=>',$param);
     echo "key is $param[0] and value is ".$param[1];
  }

 a ('hello=>world');
```

Comment: But I do not want to send an array. I want to send a key-value pair to my function.

Comment: Then use a comma operator instead.

Comment: you can't use `=>` inside the function param , try to use comma and explode the values inside the function . or try my answer by getting the key of the array

Comment: i just provide you with the only ways to do that , any thing else wont work at all .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
function a($a=array()){
    foreach($a as $k=>$v){
        echo "key is $k and value is $v";
    }
}

a(array('hello' => 'world'));
?>
```

Comment: Yes, this will do. But semantically it's now completely the same. Because I could possible pass an array of two elements and got both printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange");

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
    echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
}

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially asking for a `foreach` loop but with different syntax. It seems you only want to get the first set.

```
function a(array $arr) {
  list($k) = array_keys($arr);
  $r  = array($k=>$arr[$k]);
  unset($arr[$k]);
  return $r;
}

var_dump(a(array("Hi" => "World", "John" => "Smith")));
```

Program Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["Hi"]=>
  string(5) "World"
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/135705)